# when applying for a job through online application system, does the committee see my application immediately?

Tags: application

Is there any norm that when I apply for a job in academia (post-doc or tenure-track jobs), through online application system, does the *committee see my application immediately*? Or they have to wait until the deadline? Is this institution/country dependent?

Comment: Are you asking about academia? Are you asking about faculty positions? Student admissions? What?

Comment: For my (non-university) hiring, I wait until the posting closes to review applicants (unless it is for multiple summer student positions). HR prefers it that way. Seems unlikely the committee will meet to discuss applicants too early.

Comment: @Buffy I specified that I mean academic jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely no universal answer, since every university seems to be using its own HR systems. But it is not uncommon for the hiring committee (or individual hiring managers) to look at applicant files before the deadline to get a head start with sifting through the many many applications.

So let's assume that that is possible, then the question is whether it is an advantage to being early in the queue. I think that is a much more difficult question. I would suspect that in practice, it really doesn't matter. The people who make these decisions know that they need to wait for all files to come in before deciding, and from my own experience I can't say whether being early would be an advantage or disadvantage. It might be neither.

In your case, if you have everything ready, just submit it so that it's out of your TODO queue and out of your mind. Move on to other things mentally and be productive with them, rather than knowing that there is this thing you still need to do.